# Parsing error: Cannot read file 'tsconfig.json'.eslint

Tags: typescript, eslint, config

I have the following .eslintrs file in the root of the project:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "tsconfigRootDir": ".",
    "project": "tsconfig.json",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "sonarjs", "jest"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "airbnb-base",
    "airbnb-typescript/base",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "plugin:sonarjs/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*", "/src/kysely/types.ts"],
  "rules": {...}

}
```

And also tsconfig.json in the root:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      // https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#imports
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, // https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2577
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["typings/global.d.ts", "src/**/*", "test/**/*", "bin/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

However in src/app.module I have the following problem in the first line:
`import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';`.  Parsing error: Cannot read file 'tsconfig.json'.eslint

I have tried to add in .vscode/settings.json this code:

`"eslint.workingDirectories": ["./src"]`

but the problem still remains

Comment: Is this a vscode error?

Comment: I use vscode,yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try this in your .eslintrc file:

```
"parserOptions": {
    "project": "**/tsconfig.json"
  }
```

I hope this was helpful.